# How to combine CSV rows based on duplicate fields using Perl Text::CSV?

Tags: perl, csv

I would like to write a Perl script that would:

1. monitor a file directory for an input CSV file on a periodic basis
2. Upon file detection, open, read and merge multiple rows that have the same value for the second field/column
3. Write an updated CSV file to a new directory and finally,
4. Delete the input file.

For example, I have a CSV file with information like this:

```
"101","5555555555","DOE, JOHN "," DOE, JOHN, your trip
tomorrow from, 123 Anywhere St Apt #A, to, 100 ELSEWHERE RD APT E, is
scheduled for pickup between, 1:00 PM, and 1:30 PM"

"102","5555555555","DOE, JOHN "," DOE, JOHN, your trip
tomorrow from, 100 ELSEWHERE RD APT E, to, 123 Anywhere St Apt #A, is
scheduled for pickup between, 9:00 PM, and 9:30 PM"
```

I would like for the script to read, parse and detect the duplicate values for the second field ("5555555555") then create a new CSV file with the above records combined into one record as:

```
"101","5555555555","DOE, JOHN "," DOE, JOHN, your trip
tomorrow from, 123 Anywhere St Apt #A, to, 100 ELSEWHERE RD APT E, is
scheduled for pickup between, 1:00 PM, and 1:30 PM AND your trip
tomorrow from, 100 ELSEWHERE RD APT E, to, 123 Anywhere St Apt #A, is
scheduled for pickup between, 9:00 PM, and 9:30 PM"
```

My current Perl code successfully detects, reads and parses the file, however, I'm lost on how to detect the duplicates and combine the rows.

```
#!
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;
use Text::CSV;

$| = 1;

use constant {
    #Check for CSV files only
    SUFFIX_LIST => qr/\.(csv)$/,
    DIR_TO_CHECK => "/Users/Me/Desktop/INBOUND/",
};

my @file_list;

while (1) {

    #Recursively search the input directory for CSV files
    find ( sub {
            return unless -f;
            return unless $_ =~ SUFFIX_LIST;

                #Make sure all of the files in the file list array are unique
                if(!(grep(/^$_$/, @file_list))) {
                    push @file_list, $File::Find::name;
                }
           }, DIR_TO_CHECK 
    );

#If .csv files are found...
if (scalar(@file_list) > 0) {
    print "\nNew Item in Directory\n";

    parseFile($file_list[0]);

    #Delete input file
    unlink $file_list[0];

    print "Deleted File\n";

    #Remove the file from the file list
    shift @file_list;
} else {

    print "No New Item\n";

}

sleep 5;
}

#Subroutine to parse and compare the csv file
sub parseFile() {

my $csv = Text::CSV->new({ sep_char     => ',',
                       always_quote => 1,
                       quote_char   => '"',
                       escape_char  => '"',
                       binary       => 1,
                       auto_diag    => 1});

#Get the file that was passed to the function
my $file = $_[0] or die "CSV file not passed in subroutine\n";

#Open file for reading
open(my $data, '<', $file) or die "Could not open '$file' $!\n";

while (my $line = <$data>) {

    print $line;

    if ($csv->parse($line)) {

        my @fields = $csv->fields();

    } else {

        #warn "Line could not be parsed: $line\n";
        Text::CSV->error_input();
    }
}

close $data;
}
```

I figure what I have is wrong for the functionality that I'm looking for because I suspect that I need to read the file as a whole into memory, instead of line by line. Please help, thanks.

Comment: It looks like the first column isn't used for duplicate detection, but what about the third column? Also, do rows need to be merged in a specific order?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot The third column is not used for duplicate detection either. Ideally, the rows would be merged in the order specified by the first column. Thanks

Comment: So if, for some reason, you had a row `1,42,jack,foo` followed by `2,42,jill,bar`, would the merged result have `jack` or `jill` in the third column?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Good question... For now, at least, I'd go with having `jack`. Thus, the updated row being `1,42,jack,foo AND bar`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not into perl this days but here is my answer. Create a hashtable with second field as key. Like this.

```
%hashtbl{555555} = {
                    id => 102,                         # first field 
                    names => "doe, john",              # third field
                    msg => "DOE, JOHN, your trip..."   # last field 
                    };
```

If the key is already exists in hashtable then append its `msg`

```
if(exists $hashtbl[$KEY]) 
    $hashtbl{$KEY}->{msg} .= "AND $last_field"
```

After reading whole file, Creat a new csv file using this hashtable.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.

It isn't perfect, but it should give a big boost.  For example, you'll need to add some junk to remove the extra name in the flattened description column.

```
my $data = parseFile($path);
flatten_record($_) for @$data;
writeFile($newpath, $data);


sub csv_cols { qw/ id phone name desc / ) }

sub get_csv {
    my $csv = Text::CSV->new({
        sep_char     => ',',
        always_quote => 1,
        quote_char   => '"',
        escape_char  => '"',
        binary       => 1,
        auto_diag    => 1
    });
}


#Subroutine to parse csv file
sub parseFile() {
    my ($file) = @_;    
    die "CSV file not passed in subroutine\n"
         unless $file;

    my $csv = get_csv();

    #Open file for reading
    open(my $fh, '<', $file)
         or die "Could not open '$file' $!\n";

    $csv->column_names( csv_cols() );

    # make hash of arrays containing 
    my %by_phone;
    for my $row ( @{$csv->getline_hr_all($fh)} ) {
        my $phone = $row->{phone}
        $by_phone{$phone} = [] unless $by_phone{$phone};
        push @{$by_phone{$phone}}, $row;
    }

    return [ values %by_phone ];
}


sub flatten_record {
    my ($record) = @_;

    die "Empty record." if @$record == 0;

    if ( @$record == 1 ) {
         $record = $record->[0];
    } else {
         $record = {
             id    => $record->[0]{id},
             phone => $record->[0]{phone},
             name  => $record->[0]{name},
             desc  => "$record->[0]{desc} AND $record->[1]{desc}",
         };
    }

    return $record;
}

sub writeFile {
    my ( $path, $data ) = @_;

    open my $fh, ">", $path
        or die "Error opening '$path' for writing- $!\n";

    my $csv = get_csv();

    for my $record ( $data ) {
        my @row = @{$record}{ csv_cols() };
        $csv->print( $fh, \@row );
    }
}
```